# Git auth on EC2 works via command line within X2GO, but not by SSH

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, ssh, x2go

I work on multiple EC2 instances which each contain repos that need frequent updating. So I `ssh` to the EC2 instance, `cd` to the repo, and run `git pull`. Simple enough.

The problem is outlined in the diagram below. The `git pull` only works when I

- from my laptop, log remotely into my workstation via X2G0
- open a terminal window in the GUI
- `ssh` into the EC2 from within the workstation

It does not work when I:

- `ssh` directly to the EC2 from my laptop, even though I authenticate with the same key

It even does not work when I

- from my laptop, ssh into my workstation
- `ssh` into the EC2 from within the workstation

It is the last one that is a particular puzzler and has cost me some productive time when X2GO is not feasible. What settings could be different about opening a terminal window within the Ubuntu GUI, and then using ssh there, that are not present when I ssh to the same computer and am therefore on the command line already? All the same environment variables are present.
[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Have you already have a look as possible [ssh agent forwarding](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/using-ssh-agent-forwarding) that the x2go client might use silently?

(sorry, cannot comment at that time)